# How to create grid lines behind the flex container

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

I have a flex container in which multiple flex items are placed from top to bottom. I want some light grey colour lines behind this flex container to form something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjpuG.png).

I was trying to add one more flex container on top of this and draw lines on it, but that didn't give me any results. Can someone please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have any sample code to share? You can simply add borders to the child elements inside the flexbox. Like: `<div style="border: 1px solid red">flex child</div>` or `<div style="border-right: 1px solid blue">another flex child</div>`. There's many ways to visually decorate a layout.

Comment: Please add your code sample to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use position absolute property and use two box front box make transparent and in second box, set display grid border and you item will inside the border of grid.

Comment: if you have any problem then add you some code sample.